# How to keep client side MVC 4 validation disabled when a form is rendered again after post back?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side-validation

I have an Edit form where the **user can disable MVC 4 client side validation for certain fields.**
I am disabling the client side validation with jQuery:

```
$("#CustomerOrderNumber").prop("disabled", true);
```

This work fine when the form is first rendered.

The **problem arises when I post back the form and then redisplay the form** from a controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterImei(ImeiCustOrderNumberModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

**Because when the form is rendered again, the disabled validation in no longer disabled, and the unwanted client side validation for the field is active again.**

It seems that this is determined by the original source markup:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Customer Order Number field is required." id="CustomerOrderNumber" name="CustomerOrderNumber" type="text" value="SF1861-" />
```

**Any ideas on how to keep client side validation disabled when a form is rendered again after post back?**

I have made a little sample app illustrating my problem.
If the user disable Field B the user can post back the model without Field B being validated.
But when the page renders again, it has forgotten that Field B was disabled.
And the unwanted client side validation message for Field B renders.
I want my page to remember that Field B was disabled and stop rendering client side validation messages.
Mvc4SampleApp.zip:
http://sdrv.ms/14FUKa6

Comment: The doesn't look like it's disabling the validation, it looks like it's disabling the control, which probably means the validation framework you're using doesn't bother validating the value as disabled controls don't get posted back.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am just disabling the input field. The client side validation I am using is the one which ships with the default MVC 4 template from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem in this thread:

One of the interesting parts of the answer in the thread is the question about ModelState,
I quote from the answer:

"The state of ModelState.IsValidate will be false if the value of either FieldA or FieldB is null although it is pass in client validate.
So we should reset the ModelState of that field that we don't validate."

http://forums.asp.net/p/1934978/5507137.aspx?Re+How+to+keep+client+side+MVC+4+validation+disabled+when+a+form+is+rendered+again+after+post+back+

Answer (score 0):

After a postback the element will lose its disabled property, you will have to re-apply prop("disabled", true) to the element after the postback

Or could you use <% Html.EnableClientValidation(false); %> before the field?

Comment: I using the default MVC 4 client side validation from VS template. I have tried what you suggest                                       var cbEnabledRegisterImei = $("#EnabledRegisterImei").is(':checked');
if (!cbEnabledRegisterImei) {
    $("#CustomerOrderNumber").prop("disabled", true);
} But even when I do the unwanted client side validation error messages appear anyway. Maybe the default MVC 4 validation is quicker than jQuery?

Comment: I have made a little sample app illustrating my problem.
If the user disable Field B the user can post back the model without Field B being validated.
But when the page renders again, it has forgotten that Field B was disabled.
And the unwanted client side validation message for Field B renders.
I want my page to remember that Field B was disabled and stop rendering client side validation messages.
Mvc4SampleApp.zip:
http://sdrv.ms/14FUKa6